# FDisk Not Extending to Full Amount after LVM resize

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, fdisk

I'm using VMWare vSphere 5.1.0 Client to extend this VM's hard drive size from 5GB to 10GB. I've done that in the client and it's shows up in vSphere:

[image]

Fdisk does recognize the new hard drive size:

[image]

The problem is that the "n" command (add new partition) doesn't utilize the new space. It's allocating about 1024 bytes. It should be allocating around 5GB. This is after numerous reboots and numerous refreshes.

One thing I've noticed is that vSphere creates the partitions in a weird way. Note from the screen shot how there are two entries that represent the main hard drive: sda2 and sda5. Also, why sda5? When I try to add the new partition to the free space it only allows 3 or 4 (sda3, sda4, etc). Could the out of order partition numbering be the problem?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Without an exact text for "doesn't utilize" it's hard to tell what might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simpler for you to use a tool such as [GParted](http://gparted.org), which should be available in whatever distribution you’re using (Ubuntu presumably, given the tags).

Here’s what’s happening with `fdisk`. You currently have a small primary partition, likely `/boot`, from sector 2048 to sector 499711, followed by an extended partition from sector 501758 to sector 10483711, which contains a logical partition, your LVM PV, from sector 501760 to sector 10483711. This explains the numbering: on MBR disks, the primary and extended partitions are numbered 1 to 4, and logical partitions start from 5 (even if there aren’t four primary or extended partitions). When you ask `fdisk` to create a new partition, it can only create a new primary or extended partition because your extended partition is full. Since there’s a little room after `sda1`, `fdisk` probably picks a start sector in there, probably 499712 since that’s aligned on a mibibyte boundary; but then the partiton can only extend to sector 501757 at the most.

To fix things with `fdisk`, you should create a new primary partition and specify the start sector (10483712 works, it’s correctly aligned). Then you’ll be able to use the added space.

(You could also enlarge your extended partition and create a new logical partition, or enlarge your existing logical partiton, but that’s a little more complicated with `fdisk` — just use GParted.)

Comment: Excellent advice and directions. I went the fdisk route as I'm more confident with it's use. It worked perfectly!